# Bad system keys mapping

Tags: python, r, command-line-interface

I use remote server and R-language command line interface. The problem is that all system keys, namely Home, End, Del and most importantly Tab do not work. All keys system keys give something like "[[4~".

I had the same problem with zsh shell and I managed to fix it by following command:

```
bindkey  "^[[4~"   end-of-line
bindkey  "^[[1~"   beginning-of-line
bindkey  "^[[3~"   delete-char
```

Is it a way to fix R command line interface accordingly? I have the same issue with python as well:

```
% python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Aug  5 2015, 16:04:38)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> jnj~nwed~~
```

~ is printed then Del key is pressed.

Comment: Why do you think the problem comes from R?

Comment: I fixed shell manually so I think R has the same problem. The problem doesn't come from R - it comes from putty, ssh client, however I didn't find a fix for it.

Comment: I tried to connect from Mac and got the same result. So I assume, that the problem is actually on server side.